# Book recommendation for convergence (Almost Surely, probability, distribution) concepts in statistics.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I want to study the convergence concepts in statistics.   I am mainly interested in topics like

1. Convergence in Probability
2. Convergence in Distribution
3. Almost Surely convergence

I can't seem to find any good textbook or material that covers all the three topics in detail.

Any recommendations on what books or what material may be helpful? Thanks!

Comment: So basically you are looking for "limit theorems" book in probability. There are 1000 of them. I like this one: A History of the Central Limit Theorem: From Classical to Modern Probability Theory.
Another classical one is: Probability and Measure by Billingsley.

Comment: Any textbook for a graduate level probability course will cover this. Billingsley is already mentioned; "Probability: Theory and Examples" by Durrett, and "Probability with Martingales" by Williams are also good.

Comment: There are some good computational examples of this in Unpingco, José. Python for probability, statistics, and machine learning. Vol. 1. Springer International Publishing, 2016.